# How is aperiodic relative to ergodic property for an irreducible DTMC?

Tags: probability-distributions, markov-chains, periodic-functions, ergodic-theory

I'm asking for a intuition explanation for how periodicity relates to ergodicity, thanks.

Ergodic means the limiting distribution of DTMC exists and does not depend on the starting distribution.

Comment: Could you explain what DTMC is?

Comment: DTMC mean discrete time Markov chain

Comment: Okay, ergodicity is much more larger that just DTMC. But what exactly is your question because it sound a bit vague.